# Obfuscate entire html or JavaScript on server side before sending to visitor

Tags: javascript, php, curl, encryption, obfuscation

I want to obfuscate a entire page html or some specific JavaScript(which changes every minute), because lot of people are grabbing my html page and extracting a specific part of my JavaScript and using it.

I tried Dean Adward Packer http://joliclic.free.fr/php/javascript-packer/en/

But it still shows few things that are not to be extracted.

For Example: If i give this input with php.

> var
>   abc="aaaaaaa=1111111111111&bbbbbb=2222222222222&ccccccc=33333333333333";

It is giving a following output

> eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,d){e=function(c){return
>   c};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--){d[c]=k[c]||c}k=[function(e){return
>   d[e]}];e=function(){return'\w+'};c=1};while(c--){if(k[c]){p=p.replace(new
>   RegExp('\b'+e(c)+'\b','g'),k[c])}}return p}('7
>   6="5=4&3=2&1=0";',8,8,'33333333333333|ccccccc|2222222222222|bbbbbb|1111111111111|aaaaaaa|abc|var'.split('|'),0,{}))

Here, anyone can observe all the values and extract using php code.

I am aware of some online obfuscators like [SmartGB](https://www.smartgb.com/free_encrypthtml.php), [JSFuck](http://www.jsfuck.com/) and [Javasciptobfuscator](https://javascriptobfuscator.com/Javascript-Obfuscator.aspx).

These tools are perfect for my case, but i am not able use them on server side. 
I also know that, all above obfuscations can be easily cracked, But there is no use of cracking it once. Because, a variable of JavaScript keeps on changing every time.

All i want to do here is preventing people from automatically extracting a variable value with a simple machine code on their webserver. But manually, we cant prevent anything as javascript is public.

Comment: Can't you put this variable on the server and get it via AJAX? Then only you domain would be allowed to call that ressource (Read about same origin policy for that) and the variable couldn't be extracted anymore without a lot of effort

Comment: Ok, I can do that with ajax, but people can sniff network and identify that ajax request url.
I dont know that if i put same origin policy, can people open that url in a browser?

Comment: I think that you can make life more difficult to people that want to grab your data but avoid this completely is really impossible. So all you can do is to find the way to make the grab as difficult as possible, like (as suggested) AJAX call with cross domain origin not  allowed and something similar.

Comment: They can't sniff it if you're using HTTPS. You can get a certificate from services like Let's Encrypt. What do you mean with open in the browser? The JS? That would be returned as plain text.

Comment: @emish89 i want to make it difficult for people in any method, i thought obuscation is better for people to understand.

I will try to ajax a https url having http version as origin policy, and try to sniff it.

Comment: @chade_ i cant use https here, all my site resources are http. I cant change them. Yeah, browser shows javascript as plain text.